# Division by Multiplication and Shifiting

Tags: bit-manipulation

Why when you use the multiplication/shift method of division (for instance multiply by 2^32/10, then shift 32 to the right) with negative numbers you get the expected result minus one?

For instance, if you do 99/10 you get 9, as expected, but if you do -99 / 10 you get -10.

I verified that this is indeed the case (I did this manually with bits) but I can't understand the reason behind it.

If anyone can explain why this happens in simple terms I would be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why when you use the multiplication/shift method of division (for instance multiply by 2^32/10, then shift 32 to the right) with negative numbers you get the expected result minus one?

You get the expected result, rounded down.

`-99/10` is `-9.9` which is `-10` rounded down.

---

Edit: Googled a bit more, [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17480/Optimizing-integer-divisions-with-Multiply-Shift-i) mentions that you're supposed to handle negatives as a special case:

> Be aware that in the debug mode the optimized code can be slower, **especially if you have both negative and positive numbers and you have to handle the sign yourself**.

Comment: Ain't -9.9 supposed to be rounded to -9 if it's an integer though? For instance, if I write "int x = -9.9;" in C it will store -9 in the variable.

Comment: @DanielS The fact that C uses towards-zero rounding doesn't relate to with how your own algorithm can work. But that's probably not the issue, see the edit.